# D3.js Why do some rectangles have wider strokes than others (in a stacked bar chart)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've developed a Marimekko chart which is OK except that the lines around some rectangles appear to be 2px, whereas the rest are 1px. What can cause this?

Comment: Hard to say unless you can provide an example

Comment: I was able to adjust most of the wider lines by reducing the overall width of the chart by a few pixels. Appears that the algorithm that positions the rectangles tries to fit them into the available dimensions by padding some of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rounding issue with either the rectangles' widths or positions.

Comment: You can use shape-rendering crisp edges to help here.  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) and [Scott Murray](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes) tutorial for more info.

Comment: I don't have any control over the widths or positions other than as I noted above by controlling the overall dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I recall having this problem initially with D3.  You have to shift the offending elements by 0.5 pixels to the left or right.  That cleared up the problem for me.  I read an article that pointed out the necessity of the approach, I just don't remember where.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below somewhere in your css:

```
svg {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

Most likely you will not have the problem you described anymore. I can't guarantee it, but chances are good. I use this code for all diagrams containing svg rectangles, and for the same reason.